# Why reflection api not working in Test cases

Tags: java, reflection

I am trying to access main class variable from my test class using java reflection api but i am getting exception like below can some one guide me please

### Main class

```
package com.example.microservice.controller;

public class PrivateStatic {

    public void process() {
        String message = "data";
        if (message != null && message.equalsIgnoreCase("data")) {
            System.out.println("print message"+message);
        } else {
            System.out.println("empty message"+message);
        }
    }

}
```

### Test class

```
package com.example.microservice.controller;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.mockito.InjectMocks;
import org.mockito.Spy;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner;


@SpringBootTest
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
public class PrivateStaticTest {

    @InjectMocks
    PrivateStatic private_Static;

    @Test
    public void processTest() throws NoSuchFieldException, SecurityException, IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException {

        final java.lang.reflect.Field field = private_Static.getClass().getDeclaredField("message");
        final boolean origionalValue = field.isAccessible();
        field.setAccessible(true);
        field.set(private_Static, "data");
        field.setAccessible(origionalValue);
        private_Static.process();
    }

}
```

### Exception

```
java.lang.NoSuchFieldException: message
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredField(Class.java:2070)
    at com.example.microservice.controller.PrivateStaticTest.processTest(PrivateStaticTest.java:21)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.platform.commons.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:675)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.MethodInvocation.proceed(MethodInvocation.java:60)
```

Comment: Your `PrivateStatic` class has no `message` field. Its `process` method declares a `message` variable, but that's not something you can access using reflection.

Comment: @Aaron thanks for your suggestion ,I thought there is possibility to access method inside variables

Comment: @Aaron Java supports accessing parameters since 1.1. What’s new in 8, is that the *names* of the parameters can be retrieved when the class has been compiled with this meta information. But to invoke the method with whatever argument you like, you don’t need to know the name.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class PrivateStatic {
    private String message = "data";

    public void process() {
        if (message != null && message.equalsIgnoreCase("data")) {
            System.out.println("print message"+message);
        } else {
            System.out.println("empty message"+message);
        }
    }
}
```

make 'message' as class field
also can use `ReflectionTestUtils.setField(private_Static, "message", "data");`